# How to find the Preferences GUI Window in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-12514

I am trying to solve the ORA-12514 error. The solution is to check if the [tnsnames.ora] the [SERVICE_NAME] is a valid service name in your database.

I can't find this path ($ORACLE_HOME\network\admin) in DB directory.

But we can also check in the preferences window which I can't find in the Oracle SQL Dev. GUI. (as shown in the picture attached)[image: Preferences Window]

Comment: You've shown a screenshot of the preferences, which is confusing as you seem to be asking how to find it; have you copied that from somewhere else? If that isn't your image, then which operating system are you using? Preferences is in the Tools menu in Windows, and under the App menu (labelled 'Oracle SQL Developer') on Mac. Anyway... you only need to check `tnsnames.ora` if your connection is actually using that. If it is using a 'basic' connection then the service name is defined in the connection window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Devloper's Connections pane right click on your database name - on a context menu click Properties and then check all the data, including  SERVICE_NAME and compare it with your TNSNAMES.ora file.
Regards...